# why i see this session errors with cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

i was installed cakephp application on godaddy but something wrong i see this errors please anyone help my..the script work correctly but i cant login with users controller

```
   Warning (2): session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/var/chroot/home/content/37/7269737/tmp/sess_5fngsu7g8llj60a9075mkkgh07, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) [ROOT/7269737/html/cake/libs/cake_session.php, line 587]

    Warning (2): session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/37/7269737/html/cake/libs/debugger.php:683) [ROOT/7269737/html/cake/libs/cake_session.php, line 587]

    Warning (2): session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/content/37/7269737/html/cake/libs/debugger.php:683) [ROOT/7269737/html/cake/libs/cake_session.php, line 587]

    Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/37/7269737/html/cake/libs/debugger.php:683) [ROOT/7269737/html/cake/libs/cake_session.php, line 588]


    Warning (2): Unknown: open(/var/chroot/home/content/37/7269737/tmp/sess_5fngsu7g8llj60a9075mkkgh07, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) [Unknown, line ??]

    Warning (2): Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.
```

Comment: Similar warnings related to sessions can be due to whitespace in your controller/model files. (and others) Smacked my head after forgetting that CakePHP won't prevent this novice mistake. Remember it's best practice to not even have the ?> at the end of model/controller files. CakePHP will handle them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do following steps

1. Set permissions of write to /tmp folder that is default
2. Change php.ini to point to dir you have access instead of /tmp
3. Set Configure::write('Session.save', 'cake') and have them in cake
   app/tmp where you can manage permissions definitely.

For that you have to changed the Session settings in the **config/core.php** file. There are several options. The default is to use php.ini settings for to save sessions. 
For more details [CakePHP Core Configuration Variables](http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/view/44/CakePHP-Core-Configuration-Variables)

Comment: thank man but why i still cant login when i use sql_dumb in login.ctp i see this statment (default) 2 queries took 5 ms Nr Query Error Affected Num. rows Took (ms)
1 SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `users`  12 12 4
2 SELECT CHARACTER_SET_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLLATIONS WHERE COLLATION_NAME= 'utf8_general_ci';  1 1 1

Answer (score 1):

The direct cause of this error is that you are unable to write in the directory `/var/chroot/home/content/37/7269737/tmp/`.

Either this folder does not exist, create it.

Or it is there, and you need to give it the `0644` permission level.

Hope this helps!